# knitr: python engine output not in .md or .html

Tags: python, matplotlib, knitr

When I process my .Rmd file, there is no matplotlib img displayed. Is there a chunk option, or a different matplotlib method that is needed?

````
---
title: "Viz Examples"
output:
  html_document:
    keep_md: true
---

```{r testplot, engine="python"}
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
for c, z in zip(['r', 'g', 'b', 'y'], [30, 20, 10, 0]):
xs = np.arange(20)
ys = np.random.rand(20)

# You can provide either a single color or an array. To demonstrate this,
# the first bar of each set will be colored cyan.
cs = [c] * len(xs)
cs[0] = 'c'
ax.bar(xs, ys, zs=z, zdir='y', color=cs, alpha=0.8)

ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Z')

plt.print()

```
````

Comment: Sorry, but knitr does not support Python graphics. Only text output is supported.

Answer (score 2):

instead of `plt.print()` or `plt.show()` use

```
plt.savefig("somefilename.ext")
```

with `ext` being `png` or `jpg` or other supported output format, and any other `savefig` options, like `transparent`, then use the figure using a standard knitr mechanism.

```{r showfig,include=TRUE,echo=FALSE, results='asis'}
cat("!(./threedee.png)")

```